# Salesforce "Unfortunately the related list you're trying to view isn't in the layout" but the related list IS in the layout

Tags: lightning-experience, related-list, sales-cloud, flexipages

We are seeing this issue for this related list called "Contact Relationship"

The message says Unfortunately the related list you're trying to view isn't in the layout, but **the related list is really added in the layout**. I have checked it several times looking at the page layout assignments of the users.

The users can see the records, but the message shows up when they hover over the record, like in this screenshot:

[image: Related list problem]

This related list is being shown inside a Flexi Page, using the Related Lists component (the one that shows **all related lists** in the layout, not only one).

The name API name of this object is "HealthCloudGA__ContactContactRelation__c".

If anyone knows something it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and the lookup configuration was the solution.

One of our sales representatives couldn't see the related list and received the same message "Unfortunately, the related list you're trying to view isn't in the layout. Please get in touch with your administrator.". Her profile had the permission to read both objects and her role had the permission to read all records in those objects as well. But, when I checked the lookup field, her profile had no read permission for it, resulting on this message. Changing the Set Field-Level Security to give her read access solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be either of these:

1 - Check the FLS for lookup field on your profile/ Permission set.

2 - Add the related list to Contact/ person account layouts as well.